# How to rotate log files in Python

Tags: python, logging

I came across rotating file handler in order to rotate log file in Python, I have this piece of code.

My requirement is my log file is getting appended every few seconds, and there should be log rotation, whenever the file is beyond 1 GB of size.

This is my pseudo code, where I am trying only for 40 bytes, to check if my code works.

```
import logging
import time
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def create_rotating_log(path):
    """
    Creates a rotating log
    """
    logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    
    # add a rotating handler
    handler = RotatingFileHandler(path, maxBytes=40,
                                  backupCount=1)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    log_file = "test.log"
    create_rotating_log(log_file)
```

Now as per this code, whenever my log file reaches 40 bytes, there should be a copy of the log file as test.log.1 and my older log file should have new content.
So, I manually opened my test.log file, added contents to it to make sure size > 40 bytes and ran this piece of code, but nothing happened.My requirement is my log file is getting appended every few seconds, and there should be log rotation, whenever the file is beyond 1 GB of size.

What is the correct way of running the code for my requirement?? I am stuck here.
Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you tried using the logger? Your current code only initializes it.

Answer (score 0):

As it was adviced at the comment of @jordanm, I've tried

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def create_rotating_log(path):
    """
    Creates a rotating log
    """
    logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    
    # add a rotating handler
    handler = RotatingFileHandler(path, maxBytes=40,
                                  backupCount=1)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    log_file = "test.log"
    create_rotating_log(log_file)
    logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
    logger.info("Hello!")
```

It works.

Comment: The `logging` module doesn't monitor the file for *external* changes; it simply rotates the file when an explicit write would cause the file to exceed the threshold.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But who is talking about external log change?!

Comment: The OP did. Sorry, I mistook this for a self-answer, and chose to address the misunderstanding here rather than a comment on the question itself.

Comment: I am sorry, if my question was not clear enough. @chepner is correct, I need to monitor external file changes and rotate the log file. So I am looking for a way to modify my code to do that.

Comment: That's something the process actually modifying the file should be responsible for, not your script. (And if *multiple* programs are attempting to modify the same problem, you have a whole other set of problems to worry about.) (In Linux, you can install the `logrotate` program to handle log rotation.)